# What happens if use the same "versionCode" for multiple app releases?

Tags: android, google-play, versioning

According to the official documentation ([Versioning your applications](https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html)), the "android:versionCode" must be increased with every release of an Android application.

For release versions supposed to be uploaded to Google Play, I understand why this is necessary. However, what about nightly builds, mainly aimed at developers? For these, the versionCode would need to be generated, which is not straightforward (SCM like Git without numeric commit id, possibly multiple builds from the same commit etc.).

So, my question:

Can I just use a constant versionCode for nightly builds? What consequences will this have (apart from not being able to upload to Google Play)?

Comment: You can leave the versionCode untouched. It's years I'm updating an app and it's always at versionCode=1. But I do change its `versionName`. i.e.: `android:versionName="1.15.06.16 b"` (versionCode.YY.MM.DD daily build)

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why is this question getting downvotes? I'd appreciate a comment to understand - I though I asked a sensible, on-topic question.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I just use a constant versionCode for nightly builds?

Sure. That's what happens every time you run your app from your IDE, after all, unless you have scripted something (e.g., in Gradle) yourself to generate a unique `versionCode`.

> What consequences will this have (apart from not being able to upload to Google Play)?

Nothing that's any different from doing builds in the IDE, other than things that are more tied to doing centralized builds, more so than `versionCode` (e.g., certificate mismatch errors, unless everyone and the CI server are synchronized to use the same debug keystore).

Answer (score -1):

VersionCode is used to upgrade your apps, if you are using the same versionCode in your ease release, it will oveeride your apk file and don't able to install your new release file in which you have made some changes in it

In android you have versionCode and versionName by default. versionCode is an integer that is used by Google Play Store to make sure that you are uploading a new version of the app

For e.g. If you are releasing your fisrt app to playstore, your versionCode is android:versionCode="1" and if you're releasing your second version, your android:versionCode="2", so it will always increasing.

Comment: How is that supposed to help? You just quoted the docs (which I linked in my question).